# Sugarcrm/Suitecrm copy field via Logic Hook

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am trying to copy one field into another. One is a related field called Members and the other is called Name.

I believe doing this with Logic Hooks is the best way. So below is my logic_hooks.php

```
<?php
    // Do not store anything in this file that is not part of the array or the hook version.  This file will    
    // be automatically rebuilt in the future. 
    $hook_version = 1; 
    $hook_array = Array(); 
    // position, file, function 
    $hook_array['before_save'] = Array(); 
    $hook_array['before_save'][] = Array(1, 'Value from one field to another', 'custom/modules/ship_Membership/my.php', 'User_hook','copy');
?>
```

And here is my.php

```
class User_hook {

    function copy(&$bean, $event, $arguments)
    {

    $bean->name  = $bean->member;
    }

}
```

Here is the error I get on save

```
class User_hook { function copy(&$bean, $event, $arguments) { $bean->name = $bean->member; } }
```

Comment: The error you've posted seems to be the User_hook class, is that intentional?

Comment: Maybe you need to delete the underscore in your class name (UserHook instead of User_hook). Also, try to change the &$bean to $bean.

Answer (score 1):

It causes problems to use `&$bean` in recent versions of sugarCRM. `$bean` is already passed by reference. In the arguments for `function copy`, change `&$bean` to just `$bean`.